# Laravel 5 - access specific model on many to many relationship

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

So I am learning Laravel 5 and have a question regarding many to many relationships.  I'm building a twitter clone, and want to allow for creating tweets and retweeting.  My database setup is (as outlined in the laravel docs for a pivot table)

```
users
  - id
  - name

tweets
  - id
  - content

tweet_user
  - tweet_id
  - user_id
```

My `User` and `Tweet` model have the appropriate `belongsToMany` calls to hook up those relationships.

from **User.php**

```
public function tweets() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tweet');
}
```

from **Tweet.php**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Finally, my **tweet_user** pivot table looks like:

```
|--------------------|
| tweet_id | user_id |
|--------------------|
| 1        | 1       |
|--------------------|
| 1        | 2       |
|--------------------|
```

So to display tweets I do:

```
return view('tweets.index')->withTweets(App\Tweet::all())
```

And pass that to my view.  All good at this point, my view will display 2 tweets (as seen in the tweet_user pivot table above)  My view then has:

```
@foreach($tweets as $tweet)
   {{ $tweet->user->name }} <-issue is here
   {{ $tweet->content }} <- all good here
@endforeach
```

So since I have this setup as many to many, the `$tweet->user` is an array / collection of all users that have this tweet.  How do I access the actual user model for the current tweet in the loop above (IE user id 1 for the first loop, user id 2 for the second)?  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but do I need some other accessor on the tweet / user model? I initially had this setup as a `hasMany` / `belongsTo` relationship, so the loop above worked fine.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rename `$this->user` to `$this->users` if it were a many to many, just for the ease of reading.

Then something like:

```
@foreach($tweets as $tweet)
   @foreach($tweet->users as $user)
      {{ $user->name }}
   @endforeach
   {{ $tweet->content }} <- all good here
@endforeach
```

This is because you have a many to many relationship set up. You might want to sort by order or someway to flag the original user though.

Comment: Maybe I'm not modeling my data properly, but it does **seem** like many to many.  I've added some clarity to my OP, it would be nice to be able to tie each tweet back to it's individual record (IE user 1 created the first tweet, and user 2 created the second) without the general purpose "user 1 and 2 both tweeted this"...if that makes sense.  Without this I can't, for instance, display a username on a tweet since I only know ALL users that tweeted / retweeted something.  Thank you for the response, Chris.  Agree with everything you've posted, just need to figure out how to model this better.

Comment: It sounds like a 1 to many to be honest. A user has many tweets, but a tweet belongs to one user. Then maybe a retweet table, with something like `user_id | tweet_id | retweet_date`. Then you could set up a 1toM relationship there too and in ORM write `Tweet::find(1)->retweets()`

Comment: That's what needs to happen. Great idea. I was having trouble visualizing that relationship but this makes sense. Thanks Chris!

Comment: No drama's @Greg. I think you were really close, you're pivot table is/was essentially the `retweet table`. I am curious if there are any docs out there covering the twitter db design.... hmm